# Need query to get function execution stats in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Like below query, is there any query which can return the execution status of a function in SQL server using `sys.dm_exec_`?

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    d.object_id, 
    d.database_id, 
    OBJECT_NAME(object_id,database_id) 'proc name',
    d.cached_time,d.last_execution_time, d.total_elapsed_time,
    (d.total_elapsed_time/d.execution_count)/1000 AS [avg_elapsed_time],
    d.last_elapsed_time/1000 as last_elapsed_time,
    d.execution_count,
    *
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS d 
WHERE 
    OBJECT_NAME(object_id, database_id) = 'ssp_StoredProcedureName'
ORDER BY 
    d.Last_Execution_Time DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get exact function execution stats in versions below SQL2016.But from SQLSERVER 2016,we have [sys.dm_exec_function_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt429371.aspx).

> Applies to: SQL Server (SQL Server 2016 Community Technology Preview
>   3.2 (CTP 3.2) through current version), Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Data Warehouse Public Preview.